# Azure: How to set a default route without losing connectivity

Tags: azure, networking, routes, centos

Currently I have a Linux VM on Azure. I want to remove the default route (which is pointing to outside internet). However, if I do so I lose connectivity to the VM itself. How do I do this? I've looked into adding a load balancer to use inbound source NAT but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Thank you

Comment: How do you remove the default route?

Comment: Disable all connection by VM's firewall?

Comment: "ip route del" command

Comment: Here the output of `route`, `root@jasonvms:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
` delete them all?

Comment: No only the default one.

Comment: Can you use Azure portal to stop your VM?

Answer (score 0):

So after looking heavily into Load Balancers and such, it seems I can't do this with any Azure Resources. Here's my solution:  I create a lightweight VM to act as a router, attach it with a public IP, have it on the same private network as my Main VM. The lightweight VM is Linux with iptables routing rules to forward RDP packets to my main VM (copy from another stackoverflow thread):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination <WINDOWS SERVER IP>
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

So users would connect to the IP of the routingVM which would then forward to MainVM. Now you can delete the default routes in the mainVM without getting disconnected.